# How to show runtime in FreeRTOS Task List during debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, stm32, freertos

I'm working on an embedded software project (ARM Cortex-M7, STM32F7 microcontroller) with System Workbench for STM32, which is an Eclipse-based IDE. I've installed the "FreeRTOS Task Aware Debugger for GDB" from NXP Kinetis Design Studio (KDS)<sup>1</sup>. I want to see the runtime of each task, which should be possible with FreeRTOS and this plugin. Unfortunately, in the task list the runtime is not displayed. Instead it shows the following warning message (see also screenshot):

`Enable "configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS" macro in FreeRTOSconfig.h to see "Runtime".`

[image: screenshot]

However, I've already enabled the specified macro and other necessary macro's in FreeRTOSconfig.h:

```c
#define configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS            1

/* Definitions needed when configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS is on */
#define portCONFIGURE_TIMER_FOR_RUN_TIME_STATS configureTimerForRunTimeStats
#define portGET_RUN_TIME_COUNTER_VALUE getRunTimeCounterValue
```

Why does the plugin mention that this macro needs to be enabled when it is already enabled? What should I do to see the runtime in the Task List during debugging?

---

<sup>1</sup> Eclipse update-site: http://freescale.com/lgfiles/updates/Eclipse/KDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://community.nxp.com/thread/496226) the solution is to

```c
#define portREMOVE_STATIC_QUALIFIER 1
```

This makes sense, since the FreeRTOS source code (tasks.c) contains the following comment:

```c
/*
 * Some kernel aware debuggers require the data the debugger needs access to be
 * global, rather than file scope.
 */
#ifdef portREMOVE_STATIC_QUALIFIER
    #define static
#endif
```

and in that same file the relevant variables are indeed defined as static:

```c
#if ( configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS == 1 )
    PRIVILEGED_DATA static uint32_t ulTaskSwitchedInTime = 0UL;
    PRIVILEGED_DATA static uint32_t ulTotalRunTime = 0UL;
#endif
```

Comment: didnt fix it for me, still showing NA at stats column

Comment: @Ali80, that's quite annoying. I've been struggling with this for some time back then, and did have the feeling that was not working 100% as intended. Maybe compiling with different settings (no optimizations) might work for you. If I remember correctly, I think at some point I worked around it by adding functions in the code to print the runtime stats. The stats themselves are working fine, it's just the link to the debugger that seems to be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is determine if the problem is in the debugger plug in (I'm not sure which one this is) or in the build.  To do that place a breakpoint in xTaskIncrementTick() inside tasks.c, then view the pxCurrentTCB variable, which is a pointer to a TCB structure.  If run time stats are enabled then there should be a structure member called ulRunTimeCounter.  Is that structure member there?  If so, does it contain a value?  Even if the value is wrong, if it is there, it would seem to indicate that the issue is in the debugger plug-in.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The structure indeed contains a member `ulRunTimeCounter` (which I read about but couldn't find earlier) with the value 0. So it seems to be problem with the plug-in indeed, especially since my colleague was able to read the runtime stats from the embedded code itself (in debug logging). I'm still hoping to find a solution for the plug-in to work though.